# How can I make the code shorter when I want to modify a className by each props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to make this code shorter especially at the [if~else if]sentence.
because I want to modify a className depends on each props.

```
export defalut function Button(props) {

const { name, height, color, bgColor } = props;

let className = color + ' ' +bgColor+ ' w-20 rounded border border-black border-solid ';
  
if (height === 'small') {
    className += 'text-xs h-7';
} else if(height === 'medium') {
    className += 'text-base h-11'; 
} else if(height === 'large') {
    className += 'text-lg h-12'; 
}

return (
  <button className={className}>{name}</button>
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an object indexed by height string.

```
const classesByHeight = {
  small: 'text-xs h-7',
  medium: 'text-base h-11',
  large: 'text-lg h-12'
};
// ...
const className = `${classesByHeight[height]} ${color} ${bgColor} w-20 rounded border border-black border-solid`;
```

If the height might not be one of those, then alternate with the empty string too so you don't get an `undefined`.

```
const className = `${classesByHeight[height] ?? ''} ${color} ${bgColor} w-20 rounded border border-black border-solid`;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to replace `if else` like in the following code:

```
switch(height) {
  case 'small':
    className += 'text-xs h-7';
    break;
  case 'medium':
    className += 'text-base h-11'; 
    break;
  case 'large':
    className += 'text-lg h-12';
    break;
  default:
    className += '';
}
```